# Flutter showed Android manifest error "Overlay manifest"

Tags: android, dart, flutter

When I try to follow the flutter tutorial here.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-flutter/#2 and run the main.dart

I got the following gradle error in the terminal

> /${user}/Documents/material-components-flutter-codelabs/mdc_100_series/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
>   Error:    Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-41 value=(com.example.mdc_100_series)     has a
>   different value=(com.example.mdc100series) declared in main manifest
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-39     Suggestion: remove the overlay
>   declaration at AndroidManifest.xml    and place it in the build.gradle:
>         flavorName {            applicationId = "com.example.mdc_100_series"        }

I cant figure out what the problem is behind it.

Comment: what's the value of package= in your AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: which branch did you checkout from? `101-starter` or `102-starter_and_101-complete`? or did you modify any of the code? If you modified something, can you fork and push those code on github, or paste the content here. Those tutorials work fine for me.

Comment: I figure out the issue, first I import `material-components-flutter-codelabs` in android studio instead of `material-components-flutter-codelabs/mdc_100_series` and then some extra androidmanifest files are generated so the error showed

Answer (score 17):

Had the same problem, for me the package name in the faulty AndroidManifests (./android/app/debug & /profile) was written with underscores (`"com.example.mdc_100_series"` instead of `"com.example.mdc100series"`).
Removing those underscores resolved the problem.

Comment: Same problem here but it was the other way around :) it removed underscores in a single Manifest

Answer (score 4):

Just see your file structure. you should have 3 manifest(debug, main, profile) file. Package name should be same for all this files. Then your error will be solved.

[image]

For my case:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.***.ecart">
```

Check your package name in all 3 files.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make sure the package name in AndroidManifest.xml file

It shoud be **"com.example.mdc100series"**